# Instantiating ViewController from new storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have just made a small transition so my project loads a different storyboard as its main (did it in the info.plist).

I have my new storyboard to keep my viewController that are responsible for login screen etc. Just to make it more clear.

After the login button is tapped I want to initiate a navigationController from another storyboard:

```
func instantiateViewController(fromStoryboard storyboard: String, withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController! {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
    return viewController
}
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let viewController = instantiateViewController(fromStoryboard: "Main", withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController")
    presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Everything works correctly but one thing is driving me nuts.
After presenting the MainNavigationController from Main.storyboard its view hierarchy is not maintained.

What I mean is, the labels and buttons which supposed to be on top of another, full screen UIView (but are not its child and so they should remain) are now behind it.

What might be causing this and what is the simplest way to make them appear on top (as they do whey I open main.storyboard)

**EDIT**

I added a line of code in the rootView of the MainNavigationController in its viewDidLoad method:

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(wholeScreenView)
```

and it solved the problem.

However, does anybody know why do I have to code it myself and the views are not like in the Main.storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard is not configured the way you think it is. Your `wholeScreenView` *is* in fact in front of the other views, in the storyboard. The other views (the labels and buttons) are not subviews of `wholeScreenView`; they are subviews of the main view, and so is `wholeScreenView`. It is a later subview, so it is in front of them.

Comment: I mean this is how my views are placed: http://imgur.com/oBbt2dN. When using the Main.storyboard as the initial one they are rendered co the button and labels are on the top of the wholeScreenView. But when I instantiate the navigationController in which the viewController is embedded in, the label and button are below the wholeScreenView

Comment: Can you upload the project to github or similar so I can take a look at it for you?

Comment: Thanks for the commitment, but it is pretty big now and I really don't want to share it. The project is working now though thanks to sendSubviewToBack. I will try to recreate this in a new project tomorrow and will post the link here  :)

Comment: That will be fine! Very often, just trying to reproduce the problem in a small test project will show you what the problem _is_, and you'll solve it yourself.